# The default behavior, with no options specified, is to autogenerate an external index file

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I created a simple pet project : WeatherStation (https://github.com/curious-man/WeatherStation). 
After I applied the Hibernate framework, I build the jar file using Intelij Idea. When I tried to run jar

```
java -jar WeatherStation.jar
```

The message appears :

```
Usage: jandex [-v] [-m] [-o file-name] <directory> | <jar>
        -or-
       jandex [-d] <index-file-name>
Options:
  -v  verbose output
  -m  modify directory or jar instead of creating an external index file
  -o  name the external index file file-name
  -j  export the index file to a jar file
  -d  dump the index file index-file-name

The default behavior, with no options specified, is to autogenerate an external index file
```

I do not understand what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure you're not somehow mistakingly calling [jandex](https://github.com/wildfly/jandex)?

Comment: yes, I am sure. I do not know what jandex is